# I want to associate a file type to an installed program (Deluge), but it doesn't appear in the "Open with" menu.

Tags: bittorrent, deluge, file-association

I am trying to associate magnet links to Deluge, but it doesn't appear in the "Choose program to open with" menu, or the "More programs" menu. There is an option within Deluge to associate magnet links with the program, but that does nothing. How do I get an installed program to appear in the "Open with" menu if it isn't showing up?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to search this program "manually" with the "More Programs" menú. You'll find the executable deluge under:

```
/usr/bin/deluge
```

I tried to make an screen-shot but couldn't find a non associated file to show you how to do it.

Comment: @user264022: If this answer was helpful to you, then please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) so others may more easily find it in the future. This is also a polite way to thank the person answering your question for helping you out.